# How to read nested json file and pull information from dataframe inside dataframe in r?

Tags: r, json, tidyr, broom, rjson

I am reading a `json` file as a response from `api` which is **nested** and when I look at them in a **dataframe/table** structure format then there are **data frame under data frame**.

I have saved file at **github** location.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rjson)
library(jsonlite)
library(RCurl)
library(httr)
library(broom)

# file is available at this github link:

file_url1 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/json_response.json"

json_response <- fromjson(url(file_url1))
```

I am interested in data inside **`sessions` variable** and have tried using `map`, `tidy` but it didn't work.

```
json_response %>%

#converting dataframe cols to list
  map_if(., is.data.frame, list) %>% 
  
  # to tibble
  map_if(is_list, tibble) %>%
  mutate(sessions = map(sessions, broom::tidy),
         vaccine_fees = map(vaccine_fees, tidy)) %>% 
  unnest()
```

Above code is not working!!

Also read from another SO post [Converting nested JSON file to R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839771/converting-nested-json-file-to-r-dataframe) and tried:

```
library(rjson)

url(file_url1) %>% 
  # jsonlite::fromJSON()
  rjson::fromJSON()
```

```
map_dfr(json_response[[1]]$centers[[1]]$sessions[[1]], as.tibble)
```

But have not been able to get the correct information.

The purpose of this to get information about following fields from the json file:
`district_name`,`name`,`min_age_limit`,`available_capacity`,`available_capacity_dose1`,`vaccine` and then can apply filters on it based on the desired values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `unnest` the `sessions` variable and the `slots` variable within it to get a long dataframe.

```
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

jsonlite::fromJSON(file_url1) %>%
  .[[1]] %>% 
  unnest(sessions) %>%
  unnest(slots)

# A tibble: 280 x 20
#   center_id name    address   state_name district_name block_name pincode   lat  long from 
#       <int> <chr>   <chr>     <chr>      <chr>         <chr>        <int> <int> <int> <chr>
# 1      1273 CGHS W… CGHS Pat… Delhi      West Delhi    Not Appli…  110008    28    77 09:0…
# 2      1273 CGHS W… CGHS Pat… Delhi      West Delhi    Not Appli…  110008    28    77 09:0…
# 3      1273 CGHS W… CGHS Pat… Delhi      West Delhi    Not Appli…  110008    28    77 09:0…
# 4      1273 CGHS W… CGHS Pat… Delhi      West Delhi    Not Appli…  110008    28    77 09:0…
# 5    594035 Tihar … Tihar Ja… Delhi      West Delhi    Not Appli…  110064    28    77 09:0…
# 6    594035 Tihar … Tihar Ja… Delhi      West Delhi    Not Appli…  110064    28    77 09:0…
# 7    594035 Tihar … Tihar Ja… Delhi      West Delhi    Not Appli…  110064    28    77 09:0…
# 8    594035 Tihar … Tihar Ja… Delhi      West Delhi    Not Appli…  110064    28    77 09:0…
# 9    594035 Tihar … Tihar Ja… Delhi      West Delhi    Not Appli…  110064    28    77 09:0…
#10    594035 Tihar … Tihar Ja… Delhi      West Delhi    Not Appli…  110064    28    77 09:0…
# … with 270 more rows, and 10 more variables: to <chr>, fee_type <chr>, session_id <chr>,
#   date <chr>, available_capacity <int>, min_age_limit <int>, vaccine <chr>, slots <chr>,
#   available_capacity_dose1 <int>, available_capacity_dose2 <int>
```

Comment: thanks @Ronak Shah, this is exactly what I was looking for but never had clarity on where `tidy()` works and where `unnest()` works. Will accept the answer as soon as it let me. Thanks again !!