# json parsing in r

Tags: json, r

I am loading a heavily nested JSON in R -- the [seed data](https://web.archive.org/web/20170131212502/https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/getting-started) on league of legends games. Thanks to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430042/parse-nested-json-to-data-frame-in-r) I was able to open and get a flat data frame (100 x 14167).

```
library(json)
library(plyr)

data.json <- fromJSON(file = "data/matches1.json")
data.unlist <- lapply(data.json$matches, unlist)

funct <- function(x){
  do.call("data.frame", as.list(x))
}

data.match <- rbind.fill(lapply(data.unlist, funct)) # takes ~15 min
data.frame <- as.data.frame(data.match)
```

However, most columns have the wrong type, and I run into [anomalies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288485/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-column-to-numeric-type) when converting. Is there a way of converting the columns automatically to characters/factors or numerics? Or is this wishful thinking? :)